# Jmeter pass variables to a test fragment

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am getting to grips with Jmeter and have used test fragments so I can attempt a modular approach.

I have a setup like this:

```
-- Test fragment (login)
  -- HTTP Cookie Manager
  -- HTTP Request (post with username and password)
-- Test fragment (logout)
  -- HTTP Cookie Manager
  -- HTTP request (includes cookie)

--Thread Group
  -- Transaction Controller
    -- Module Controller (login)
    -- HTTP Cookie manager
    -- HTTP Request
    -- Module Controller (logout)
    -- Results Tree
```

This all works well, but what I would like to do is be able to pass variables to the test fragment, perhaps so i can use a while controller to loop through a csv of username and passwords and pass these to the test fragment. Is this possible?

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass usernames and passwords to your post request through a csv file, then use **csv data set config** element. You have to add it before your post request in your script. 
 Check [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) and [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) from jmeter user manual for more information.

Comment: this is what i did, and modified my test fragment to accept the variables. Was pleasantly surprised it picked up the variables. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can pass variables to the test fragment - I would suggest you to use a Parameterized controller - You can check this article on creating modular/reusable test scripts in JMeter - http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-modularizing-test-scripts/